# Box2D: Applying force at opposite ends of rectangular body in order to achieve 2D drone like simulation. Unable to locate world/local points correctly

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

So I am trying to achieve drone like simulation in libgdx box2d. I want to control forces on two thrusters by individual keys. Here's the code:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Q)) {
    Vector2 point = drone.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(-Constants.DRONE_WIDTH, Constants.DRONE_HEIGHT));

    double angle = drone.getAngle();
    float fx = (float) (THRUST_FORCE * Math.cos(angle));
    float fy = (float) (THRUST_FORCE * Math.sin(angle));
    Vector2 force = new Vector2(fx, fy);

    drone.applyForce(point, force, true);
}

if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
    Vector2 point = drone.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(Constants.DRONE_WIDTH, Constants.DRONE_HEIGHT));

    double angle = drone.getAngle();
    float fx = (float) (THRUST_FORCE * Math.cos(angle));
    float fy = (float) (THRUST_FORCE * Math.sin(angle));
    Vector2 force = new Vector2(fx, fy);

    drone.applyForce(point, force, true);
}
```

So in theory body should move up when both keys pressed without any rotation. But only the left end lifts up whether I press Q or UP key. Right end never gets lifted. So I think force is applied at wrong points. I don't know why this is happening. Please help!!!

EDIT: Another strange thing:

```
Vector2 force = new Vector2(0, THRUST_FORCE);
drone.applyForce(drone.getWorldCenter(), force, true);
```

When I do this, still only the left ends lifts up!!!!

Comment: As a shot in the dark... what happens if you reverse the `if` statements? I.e. what happens if you put the UP key check and handling expression first (and the Q key check and handling code second)? Is the right end still not getting lifted or does the right end lift now but not the left?

Comment: Still only the left ends lifts up!!! It's grtting on my nerves. Feels like everything i've been learning was all wrong. So weird.

Comment: Be sure to get the ordering of parameters correct to the `applyForce` method (maybe it's just the edit though that made that mistake). As for only the left end is lifting, what happens if you use the get-world-center java body method  and then apply the forces to that point offset by the negative and positive `DRONE_WIDTH` values? I'm wondering because at least the 2.3.2 C++ Box2D code for `applyForce` shows torque getting calculated as `m_torque += b2Cross(point - m_sweep.c, force)` where m_sweep.c is what the `GetWorldCenter` method gives.

Comment: See i made an edit. when i pass getWorldCenter vector to applyforce then also only the left end lifts up. So, get worldcenter also isn't returning correct values. However, if i use drone.applyForceCenter() only then force to center is applied

Comment: Are you on any other channel where i can message you personally?